# How to change the view color after pressing the TouchableHighlight?

Tags: typescript, react-native

In my scenario, I am having UI within render like below code. Here, whenever I am pressing the touchableHighlight then I need to change the color in multiple different mode. Here, Multiple TouchableHighlight I have loaded into grid component but below actions should happen only on which is user pressing that particular TouchableHighlight.

- By Default It should be view radius white and inside circle gray
- When I am pressing the the TouchableHighlight  component radius
  color need to change, If tapping goes long time then need to change
   radius color red
- If my server responded then need to change  radius green.

How to achieve above modes in touchableHighlight?

**My CodeBelow**

```
 <View style={{
                    alignItems: "center",
                    height: 67,
                    width: 68,
                    borderRadius: 40,
                    borderWidth: 3,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.WHITE,
                    borderColor: this.state.borderRadiusColor,
                  }}>
                  <TouchableHighlight
                     onPress={()=>{
                      let value = item.text ? 0 : 1;
                      this.SwitchToggle(value, item.valueParam);
                     }}
                     underlayColor={Colors.WHITE}
                     // style={this.state.buttonNumber == index ? SwitchingStyles.switchButtonPressed : SwitchingStyles.switchButtonOff}
                     style={SwitchingStyles.switchButtonOff}
                     onHideUnderlay={this._onHideUnderlay.bind(this)}
                     onShowUnderlay={this._onShowUnderlay.bind(this)}>
                    <Text></Text>
                  </TouchableHighlight>
                  </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of PressEvent props to change the state of your borderRadius color.

In case you want to change it to orange when short pressed and red when long pressed use this:

```
                  <TouchableHighlight
                     onPress={()=>{
                      this.setState({borderRadiusColor: 'orange'});
                      let value = item.text ? 0 : 1;
                      this.SwitchToggle(value, item.valueParam);
                     }}
                     onLongPress={()=>{
                      this.setState({borderRadiusColor: 'red'});
                      let value = item.text ? 0 : 1;
                      this.SwitchToggle(value, item.valueParam);
                     }}
                     underlayColor={Colors.WHITE}
                     style={SwitchingStyles.switchButtonOff}
                     onHideUnderlay={this._onHideUnderlay.bind(this)}
                     onShowUnderlay={this._onShowUnderlay.bind(this)}>
                    <Text></Text>
                  </TouchableHighlight>
```

And then wherever you handle your server response, change the color state to green.

Comment: Great answer but this TouchableHighlight I placed inside Gird so if I do above one it is changing all the TouchableHighlight colors. I have grid cell index, by using that how to do only on pressed button color change?

Comment: so if you know the number N of TouchableHighlights in advance you can change your borderRadiusColor state to an array length N, and then use the grid cell index like so: this.state.borderRadiusColor[grid_index]

Comment: Could you please update your answer for Grid cell touchable highlight. The above code If I update entire grid cell button color is updating.

Comment: I can do that if you update your question such that I can see how your multiple TouchableHighlights are organized exactly